# Problem with node.js twitch bot shoutout command

Tags: node.js, command, chatbot, twitch

When the !so command is used it works fine if you use "@" at the start of the username but if you just do !so without the @ the username is deleted from the output.. here's my code.

```
client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, user, self) => {
if(self) return;
const badges = tags.badges || {};
const isBroadcaster = badges.broadcaster;
const isMod = badges.moderator;
const isModUp = isBroadcaster || isMod;
const args = message.slice(1).split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


// so command
if(isModUp) {
if(command === 'so') {
const args = message.slice(1).split('@');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
client.say(channel, `Go check out ${args.join(' ')}! www.twitch.tv/${args.join(' ')}`); 
}
}
```

I tried changing "const args = message.slice(1).split('@');" to "const args = message.slice(1).split(' ');" but that method left the "@" in the output link.

I'm hoping to be able to use the command either by using !so "username" or !so "@username"

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you don't include the "@", the `.split('@')` is only converting your string into an array of one element. Then, the following `.shift()` is removing that unique element:

```
// message -> "!so user"
const args = message.slice(1).split('@');
// args -> ["so user"]
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
// args -> []
```

Just in case it can help you, I am removing the "@" if it is present. My "!so" command:

```
const commandArgs = message.split(' ');
const command = commandArgs.shift()?.toLowerCase?.();

// ...

const userName = commandArgs.shift();
if (userName[0] === '@') {
  userName.shift(); // Here, userName is an string.
}

client.say(
  channel,
  `... @${userName}, ... -> https://twitch.tv/${userName}`
);
```